# how to add custom order variable value to new order email

Tags: transactional-mail

I have created a custom field in "sales_flat_order" table and updating it over "checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after" event. 
Now I want to send this field's value in new order email to customer.
How can I do this ? by override any block or something else.

Comment: Prateek, do you have any idea regarding this..?

Comment: got a solution, its setting parameter for order email template in file - `Sales/Model/Order.php` , in below funcions -

Below version 1.9.2 -
`public function sendNewOrderEmail()`

And in and above 1.9.2
`public function queueNewOrderEmail()`

So, just override it as per the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put the answer in here instead in the comment

The solution:
- set the parameter for the order email template in the file
`Sales/Model/Order.php`

in below funcions

Below version 1.9.2 - `public function sendNewOrderEmail()`

And in and above 1.9.2 `public function queueNewOrderEmail()`

So, just override it as per the requirement.